# How to setup NTLM V2 for Sharepoint 2013/ 2016?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-2016, ntlmv2

I am working on SharePoint 2013 onpremise REST APIs.
I am able to configure my web application with BASIC and NTLM. I would like to setup on-premise instance with **NTLM V2**.

Could you please help us How to setup NTLM V2 on SharePoint 2013/ 2016?

Please suggest.